# Wrap around groups of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of elements and I want to group them with div starting with the class HEADER and end it if the class is BREAK or the last element.

So the code below,

```
<div class="test">Test 0</div>
<div class="header">Header 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="header">Header 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
<div class="break">Break 1</div>
<div class="header">Header 3</div>
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 5</div>
<div class="header">Header 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 6</div>
<div class="break">Break 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 7</div>
<div class="header">Header 5</div>
<div class="test">Test 8</div>
```

Would become,

```
<div>
    <div class="test">Test 0</div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="test">Test 1</div>
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="test">Test 2</div>
        <div class="test">Test 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="break">Break 1</div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="test">Test 4</div>
        <div class="test">Test 5</div>
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="test">Test 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="break">Break 2</div>
    <div class="test">Test 7</div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="test">Test 8</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for these type of question its better to create fiddel ot code snippets

Comment: i have made this http://jsfiddle.net/xyzsgzb2/ for you check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall) method as shown below:

```js
$(".header").each(function() {
  var $group = $(this).nextUntil(".break").addBack();
  if (!$(this).closest(".group").length)
    $group.wrapAll('<div class="group"/>');
});
```

```css
.group {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Test 0</div>
<div class="header">Header 1</div>
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
<div class="header">Header 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
<div class="break">Break 1</div>
<div class="header">Header 3</div>
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 5</div>
<div class="header">Header 4</div>
<div class="test">Test 6</div>
<div class="break">Break 2</div>
<div class="test">Test 7</div>
<div class="header">Header 5</div>
<div class="test">Test 8</div>
```

---

Reference:

- [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each)
- [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback)
- [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil)
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Comment: Wonderful! Your code save me big time. Thanks a lot TJ.

Comment: @T J The code is working but how do i add another break point? For example ".break2" ?

Comment: @RussellPabon where do you want to add another break..?